# When I try to put "Form.KeyPreview = True" it's giving me "Decleration Expected" Error message

Tags: vb.net, keypreview

I'm new with KeyPreview. I've read a bit about it but I still don't understand everything. In my code I put "Form.KeyPreview = True" But then it says "Declaration expected" under Form. I don't know what I need to declare though. I don't know if I need to put it under a private sub, but I need help. Here is the code snippet

```
Public Class Form1

Form.KeyPreview = True
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Select Case True
```

[Here is a picture of the code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gYmB.png)
 Anyways thanks for your help.

Comment: code needs to be in a method.  move that to `Sub New` or form load (or just set the property int he designer)

Comment: Continuing @Plutonix's comment: You should also refer to the current form via `Me` instead of `Form`, so the snippet will be: `Me.KeyPreview = True`.